# Hikvision camera SDK [Delphi] - error 7 NET_DVR_NETWORK_FAIL_CONNECT

Tags: delphi, hikvision

I cannot connect to hikvison camera, NET_DVR_Login_V30 returns -1, and NET_DVR_GetLastError returns 7: 
"NET_DVR_NETWORK_FAIL_CONNECT - Connecting device failed. Device offline or network connection timed out."

Camera is 100% online and configured, I can successfully connect using ClientDemo.exe!

In wireshark I see that it don't even try to connect.

```
type
  LPNET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30 = ^NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30;

  NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30 = Record
    sSerialNumber: array [0 .. 47] of BYTE;
    byAlarmInPortNum: BYTE;
    byAlarmOutPortNum: BYTE;
    byDiskNum: BYTE;
    byDVRType: BYTE;
    byChanNum: BYTE;
    byStartChan: BYTE;
    byAudioChanNum: BYTE;
    byIPChanNum: BYTE;
    byZeroChanNum: BYTE;
    byMainProto: BYTE;
    bySubProto: BYTE;
    bySupport: BYTE;
    bySupport1: BYTE;
    byRes1: BYTE;
    wDevType: Word;
    byRes2: array [0 .. 15] of BYTE;
  end;

  (...)

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ErrorValues: LongWord;
  lUserID: LONG;
  struDeviceInfo: NET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30;
  DVRIP, DVRUserName, DVRPassWord: String;


function NET_DVR_Init(): boolean; stdcall;
  external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name 'NET_DVR_Init';

function NET_DVR_Cleanup(): boolean; stdcall;
  external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name 'NET_DVR_Cleanup';

function NET_DVR_SetConnectTime(dwWaitTime, dwTryTimes: DWORD): boolean;
  stdcall; external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name 'NET_DVR_SetConnectTime';

function NET_DVR_SetReconnect(dwInterval: DWORD; bEnableRecon: boolean)
  : boolean; stdcall; external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name 'NET_DVR_SetReconnect';

function NET_DVR_GetLastError(): LongWord; stdcall;
  external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name 'NET_DVR_GetLastError';

function NET_DVR_Login_V30(sDVRIP: PChar; wDVRPort: Word; sUserName: PChar;
  sPassword: PChar; lpDeviceInfo: LPNET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30): LONG; stdcall;
  external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name 'NET_DVR_Login_V30';

function NET_DVR_Logout_V30(lUserID: LONG): boolean; stdcall;
  external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name 'NET_DVR_Logout_V30';


implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DVRIP := 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
  DVRUserName := 'demo';
  DVRPassWord := '12345';

  NET_DVR_Init();

  NET_DVR_SetConnectTime(2000, 1);
  NET_DVR_SetReconnect(10000, true);

  lUserID := NET_DVR_Login_V30(PChar(DVRIP), 8000, PChar(DVRUserName),
    PChar(DVRPassWord), @struDeviceInfo);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('lUserID:' + inttostr(lUserID));

  ErrorValues := NET_DVR_GetLastError();
  Memo1.Lines.Add('ErrorValues:' + inttostr(ErrorValues));

  NET_DVR_Logout_V30(lUserID);
  NET_DVR_Cleanup();

end;
```

Regards

Comment: Which Delphi Version do you use? Maybe you need to use PAnsiChar instead of PChar. I don't know the SDK.

Comment: Delphi 10.1 Berlin. PAnsiChar instead of PChar makes no difference. The above code found somewhere on the internet is quite old.

Comment: Not familiar with the SDK but do you have an actual DVR setup?  If not, maybe the API has a way to connect directly to the camera...

Comment: SDK consists of 2 dll's in it's basic form. I'm using the same dll's as ClientDemo that connects properly.
Camera has an API over http and it works ok, but it has some drawbacks, so I'm trying with SDK.

Comment: @GWimpassinger PAnsiChar was the key! One thing I didn't correct was declaration of variables from String to AnsiString. Thx.

Comment: @tomek Need to talk with you, please! What is your email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work the original code need 2 fixes:
1. Correct variable declarations from String to AnsiString
2. Pass strings to dll as PAnsiChar (as G Wimpassinger pointed)

```
DVRIP, DVRUserName, DVRPassWord: AnsiString;
...

function NET_DVR_Login_V30(sDVRIP: PAnsiChar; wDVRPort: Word; sUserName: PAnsiChar;
  sPassword: PAnsiChar; lpDeviceInfo: LPNET_DVR_DEVICEINFO_V30): LONG; stdcall;
  external 'HCNetSDK.dll' name 'NET_DVR_Login_V30';
...

lUserID := NET_DVR_Login_V30(PAnsiChar(DVRIP), 8000, PAnsiChar(DVRUserName),
  PAnsiChar(DVRPassWord), @struDeviceInfo);
```